# Check whether a track appears more than once in a playlist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently using the Spotify playlist dataset. I would like to check whether a song occurs more than once in a playlist.
How could I best do that?

So look in a playlistid to see if the trackid appears several times. How can you best solve this?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'trackid': [1, 2, 3, 1]
     , 'artist_name': ['AronChupa', 'AronChupa', 'Scooter', 'AronChupa']
     , 'track_name': ['I am an Albatraoz', 'Little Swing', 'How much is the fish?', 'Little Swing']
     , 'playlistid': [1,1,1,3]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df.head(5))
```

[image]

I tried something like

```
     counts = df['trackid'].value_counts()
     df[df['trackid'].isin(counts.index[counts > 1])]
```

But this gives me only the rows with trackid appear more than 1 in the dataframe.

---

Some rows of the Spotify Playlist dataset

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=["artist_name", "track_name", "playlistid"])]
```

Meaning, "show me all the records where it's the same artist and track name, appearing in the same playlist more than once"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!